# Ошибка в statusbar

Tags: база-данных, delphi, delphi-7

Прога должна связываться с бд и выводить инфу оттуда. В строке `TStatusBar.Panels[1].Text := IntToStr(dstBrigades.RecordCount);` пишет ошибку при запуске  `[DCC Error] main030.pas(49): E2233 Property 'Panels' inaccessible here`.
По идее в этой строке вместо `TStatusBar` должно быть написано `StatusBar1`, но когда так пишу то он подчеркивает эту строку и пишет ошибку "Неопределенный идентификатор".
Как это исправить? Пишу на Delphi7

```
unit main030;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, DM, Grids, DBGrids, StdCtrls, Menus, ComCtrls, ExtCtrls, ActnList;

type
  TfmMain = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    mFile: TMenuItem;
    mRefresh: TMenuItem;
    mExit: TMenuItem;
    buRefresh: TButton;
    buExit: TButton;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
   // procedure mFileClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  end;

var
  fmMain: TfmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

       procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
         begin
  //Открыть базу данных
  with DM.Datamodule1 do
  begin
    //Устанавливаем связь с базой данных
    dbBrigades.Connected := True;
    //Активизируем запрос
    dstBrigades.Active := True;
    //Выводим количество записей в таблице
       TStatusBar.Panels[1].Text := IntToStr(dstBrigades.RecordCount);
  end;
end;

procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  with DM.Datamodule1 do
  begin
    //Запрос закрывается.
    dstBrigades.Active := False;
    //Закрываем связь с базой данных
    dbBrigades.Connected := False;
  end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: подчеркивает, потому что внутри `with..do`. вынесите эту строку из `with..do` и верните обратно `statusBar1`

Comment: либо используйте `self.statusBar1...`

Comment: Так если вынести из  `with ... do`, то как он  выведет инфу из бд? 
Я попробовал и то, и то, ничего не работает, пишет неопределенный идентификатор

Comment: Вы как-то криво обрезали код. Куда подевались `TfmMain.FormShow`?

Comment: тоже пришлось убрать, подчеркивает `"TfmMain" does not contain a member named  "FormShow"`

Comment: Лишнего ВЫ поубирали явно или руками похозяйничали . Не мешайте Delphi сделать методы формы. Выберите в инспекторе Events-OnShow и даблклик - создатся правильное описание и заготовка метода.

Comment: Я добавил его в эту строку `procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin.....` 
Но ничего не поменялось, таже самая ошибка c statusbar

Comment: "Эта строка"  (точнее, совокупность действий и их результат) неправильная

Comment: Я делаю по методичке, которую нам дали, там по идее должно быть правильно, но не работает все равно

Comment: Я добавил `Tfm.Main` в `FormShow` и `FormClose`. вроде бы все исправилось, но теперь ошибка в `Application.CreateForm(TfmName, fmName);` в файле 
`program prSimpl030;

uses
  Forms,
  main030 in 'main030.pas' {fmName},
  DM in 'DM.pas' {DataModule1: TDataModule};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TfmName, fmName);
  Application.CreateForm(TDataModule1, DataModule1);
  Application.Run;
end.
` 
Пишет необъявленный идентификатор TfmName и fmName

Comment: Астанавитесь!!! Метод безудержного тыка не поможет. Инструкция в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Уберите из кода все рукописные артефакты (если наворотили слишком много, то лучше начать новый проект), в частности:

```
procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
...

     procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
         begin
  //Открыть базу данных
  with DM.Datamodule1 do
  begin
    //Устанавливаем связь с базой данных
    dbBrigades.Connected := True;
    //Активизируем запрос
    dstBrigades.Active := True;
    //Выводим количество записей в таблице
       TStatusBar.Panels[1].Text := IntToStr(dstBrigades.RecordCount);
  end;
end;

procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  with DM.Datamodule1 do
  begin
    //Запрос закрывается.
    dstBrigades.Active := False;
    //Закрываем связь с базой данных
    dbBrigades.Connected := False;
  end;
end;
```

Выберите форму в дизайнере, слева в инспекторе объектов перейдите на вкладку `Events`, щёлкните даблкликом на `OnShow` и `OnClose` - создадутся заготовки методов

Впишите нужный код

Answer (score 0):

В секции `implementation` вместо

```
procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
```

должно быть

```
procedure TfmMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
```

Это метод класса TfmMain, а не процедура.

Тогда и ошибка "Неопределенный идентификатор" пропадет, т.к. `StatusBar1` - член класса `TfmMain` и доступен из всех его методов.